# Angular http get no response from api

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I am trying to get any information with Angular from the local api that I have created in Ruby, Sinatra platform. I am sure that the api is running on the port 4567 since I can see the data if i access m it directly through web interface. When I do that I see this (just next to the number 0 there is like a small arrow so it is possible to minimize the  details of the object):

```
  0
 id "1"
 name   "Company-A21"
 address    "Gany-A11"
```

If I want to see RAW data I get this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Company-A21","address":"Gany-A11"}]
```

On the "other side" I am running apache2 and this HTML file:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{company.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{company.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the hello.js:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies/2').
    then(function(response) {
            $scope.company = response.data;
    });
 });
```

Why I can not see response?
I just started to practice Angular and I stuck here...

Comment: If your data is exactly what you have then it is formatted incorrectly. You showed: `[{"id":"1","name":"Company-A21","address":"Gany-A11"]` but it should be `[{"id":"1","name":"Company-A21","address":"Gany-A11"}]` or like this `{"id":"1","name":"Company-A21","address":"Gany-A11"}`

Comment: I have it as your second example array [ { } ]

Comment: See my comment in Ronnie's answer below. I think his answer should help you the most.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array of objects so you'd output it like: `{{company[0].id}}`

You probably followed an example using `ng-repeat` which would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies">
   <p>The ID is {{company.id}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{company.name}}</p>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/21/

Comment: Could you Please expand your answer just a little bit more. I see what is my problem, I don't know how to return the object inside of an array

Comment: Since your data is in an array you either need to do an `ng-repeat` as shown above to walk through all of the data within the array. That would replicate the `<div>` and the two `<p>` tags once per entry in the array. Or you can access a single entry within the array like Ronnie demonstrated by using `{{company[0].id}}` and `{{company[0].name}}`. Although I would probably use `$scope.companies` as my variable name or change your controller code to read `$scope.company = response.data[0];` if you know you will only ever get one entry back.

Comment: @Intervalia beat me to it! Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init to execute your get request. Implement your api call under a method:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.getCompany = function(){
       $http.get('http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies/2').
         then(function(response) {
            $scope.company = response.data;
         });
       }
 });
```

and use it in ng-init:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello" ng-init="getCompany()">
            <p>The ID is {{company.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{company.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```